# If another child other that first child has class, remove class from first child in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

Struggling with some logic here.

I need a jQuery function that will assess if any other child element has a class, and if so remove that class from the first child, and if no other child has the class, add it to the first child.

**Edit: HTML Example**

- All
  First
  Second
- Third

```
<ul>
  <li class="selected">All</li>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you give examples of the HTML and various cases to clarify?

Comment: So you basically want something like when a li is clicked on that element it should be selected, and all other elements "reset" aka class "selected" removed?

Comment: no, I want to allow multiple selections, I  just don't want ALL selected when any others are selected, and when none are selected, automatically select ALL

Comment: I think you'll have to provide some more examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve : [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LzSTP/) ?